# Cross Page Posting & Custom Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use a Custom Validator (which validates on the server) and a button (it's PostbackUrl = "Page2.aspx").

When I press the button the browser show always Page2 without checking if the page is valid.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The page2.aspx is different page from the page you start ? -I mean that why you use PostBackUrl ? You have a Page1, and after click you go to Page2 ?

Comment: Yes, you start at Page1 and when you click the button you go to Page2

Answer (score 0):

The server side validation is not executed as the "WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions" onclick event handler added by asp.net will change the "action" attribute of the form to be whatever is set the "PostbackURL"  button attribute, in your case "page2.aspx". This means the postback will go straight to "Page2.aspx" by passing the page the custom validator is on so it's server side validation will never fire. However whatever client side validation you have will execute before the page is submitted.

The way to solve this is to add a server side click event hander for the button and redirect to page2 to that method if the page is valid as follows:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Button1.PostBackUrl = string.Empty;
        this.Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
        this.CustomValidator1.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(this.CustomValidator1_ServerValidate);
    }

    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Page.IsValid)
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("~/page2.aspx");
        }
    }

    void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        // validation logic here
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Keith